# Проблема с кодировкой в поисковой строке при открытии браузера из Python

Tags: python, кодировка, macos

Проблема следующая, при передачи русских символов, мак открывает поисковую систему и вместо поиска, выдает в поиск не понятные символы.
Ниже пример на картинке.

Что я пробовал сделать, пользовался функциями encode(), decode() это не помогло.
Менял браузер, не помогло.
Нужна помощь как исправлять данную проблему

```
a = "Привет"

webbrowser.open(f'https://yandex.ru/search/?text={a}')

print('Original string:', a)
```

В строке поиска отображается:

[image]

Comment: А так? `from urllib.parse import quote_plus` `webbrowser.open(f'https://yandex.ru/search/?text={quote_plus(a)}')`

Comment: Вопрос ещё в какой кодировке сам файл с питоновским кодом. А на экран через `print` нормально печатается, да?

Comment: Да, на экран печатает все окей, только когда браузер отрывает, там не понятные символы, с английскими все хорошо

Comment: @NikitaMileshin мой вариант попробовали в итоге?

Comment: @insolor спасибо, сработало, столько всего перерыл, неделю навреное лазил, спасибо еще раз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Текст запроса внутри URL нужно кодировать с помощью [процентного кодирования](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), например вместо "Привет" должно быть `%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82`. На python это можно сделать с помощью функции [`quote_plus`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus) из модуля `urllib.parse`

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

a = "Привет"

webbrowser.open(f'https://yandex.ru/search/?text={quote_plus(a)}')
```